# Jomsocial showing JQuery text on pages

Tags: joomla, jomsocial

On my site Jomsocial is showing the JQuery output as text in the page.

I have no idea how to get rid of it and would really welcome any ideas.

Please see this screen shot:

http://www.fabulous-women.co.uk/JS_AD.png

Many thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Have you hacked any core files. Try to re-install Jomsocial once again.

Answer (score 0):

Try switching to the Jomsocial default template first.

Is your jomsocial up to date, or is it a stable release?

It seems like there is an unterminated string or tag causing all the code to be output instead...

Comment: any ideas how I would track it down? I am using YooTheme templates